# O que é o método miniMax?

Tags: algoritmo

O [**Wikipédia**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) define o minimax como:

> Em teoria da decisão, o minimax (ou minmax) é um método para minimizar
>   a perda máxima possível. Pode ser considerado como a maximização do
>   ganho mínimo (maximin).(...)

Lá também exemplifica com um algoritmo:

```
ROTINA minimax(nó, profundidade)
    SE nó é um nó terminal OU profundidade = 0 ENTÃO
        RETORNE o valor da heurística do nó
    SENÃO SE o nó representa a jogada de algum adversário ENTÃO
        α ← +∞
        PARA CADA filho DE nó
            α ← min(α, minimax(filho, profundidade-1))
        FIM PARA
        RETORNE α
    SENÃO
        α ← -∞
        PARA CADA filho DE nó
            α ← max(α, minimax(filho, profundidade-1))
        FIM PARA
        RETORNE α
    FIM SE
FIM ROTINA
```

Alguém poderia explicar melhor o que é este método do miniMax e uma aplicação dele em uma situação real?

Comment: @LuizVieira minha pergunta não é diretamente ligada a AI, mas vou da uma lida na outra pra ver se a resposta atende.

Comment: Eu sei que não é, mas de fato o título lá está restringindo o conteúdo porque ele também se aplica à sua dúvida do jeito que ela está aqui. Dá uma olhada, e se a sua dúvida for mais específica edite a questão para adicionar os detalhes (que dai eu retiro o voto pra fechar como duplicada). :)

Comment: @LuizVieira infelizmente onde estou não da pra ver as imagens, mas o texto responde ao atendido realmente, obrigado pela indicação precisa. :)